# Sheets lookup based on 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure a way to search based on a name in column A and date in column B what is the salary of that person. The salaries are in another worksheet, also split by the name in column A and date in column B and salary in column C.

I am doing this in Google Sheets.

Below is shown what I need.

Table 1:

| Name | Date | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 31/12/2020 | $5,000 |
| John Doe | 31/12/2020 | $4,500 |
| John Smith | 31/11/2020 | $4,780 |

Table 2:

| Name | Date | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 31/12/2020 | **=formula here to find appropriate salary** |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `QUERY()` function in google sheet.

```
=QUERY(A2:C4,"Select C Where A='" & A9 & "' AND B='" & B9 & "'")
```

You can also use `INDEX/MATCH()` like

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(C2:C4, MATCH(A9&B9,A2:A4&B2:B4,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2&B2, {'Table 1'!A:A&'Table 1'!B:B, 'Table 1'!C:C}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In google sheets you can try:

`=FILTER(C1:C3,A1:A3=E2,B1:B3=F2)`

[image]